# OpenCV putText without a GUI thread, or named window?

Tags: c++, opencv, user-interface

I would like to put a UTF8 text using a specific font on my `cv::Mat` and I don't want to use OpenCV's GUI elements (windows). I compiled OpenCV 3.4.3 against Qt 5.11.1 and it works fine.

I understand that calling `cv::addText` function crashes duo to lack of GUI thread, in case no window is created by `cv::namedWindow` or `cv::window`. So I want to know if there is a way to somehow hide a previously created window, or even start GUI thread without actually having a window?

Comment: I don't think `cv::putText()` has to do anything with GUI thread, it works without `cv::namesWindow`

Comment: @ZdaR `cv::putText()` does not supporst TTF Fonts nor UTF8 text, not BiDi algorithm.

Comment: Then you can use some other Open Source utility to write text on images. Actually the OpenCV functionality of `cv::putText()` is pretty limited and is only used for debugging purposes with limited options of fonts etc, I would recommend you using some other library for this specialise use case.